# Getting an error when giving command like "mvn install"

Tags: java, apache, maven

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:unpack (unpack-xsd-files) on project jointIndustryJava: Either artifact or artifactItems is required -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:unpack (unpack-xsd-files) on project jointIndustryJava: Either artifact or artifactItems is required 
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:347)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: Either artifact or artifactItems is required 
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.dependency.fromConfiguration.AbstractFromConfigurationMojo.verifyRequirements(AbstractFromConfigurationMojo.java:125)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.dependency.fromConfiguration.UnpackMojo.doExecute(UnpackMojo.java:99)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.dependency.AbstractDependencyMojo.execute(AbstractDependencyMojo.java:167)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 19 more
```

Any idea......

Comment: post your `pom.xml`

Comment: does your `pom.xml` contain the line `<artifactId>myArtifact</artifactId>`?

Answer (score 2):

Either your artifactItems are null or left empty. You must specify artifactItems in your maven-dependency-plugin:

```
...
<configuration>
          <artifactItems>
            <artifactItem>
              <groupId>[ groupId ]</groupId>
              <artifactId>[ artifactId ]</artifactId>
              <version>[ version ]</version>
              <type>[ packaging ]</type>
              <overWrite>[ true or false ]</overWrite>
              <outputDirectory>[ output directory ]</outputDirectory>
              <destFileName>[ filename ]</destFileName>
            </artifactItem>
          </artifactItems>
          <!-- other configurations here -->
        </configuration>
...
```